# Can I use small part of graphic in my GitHub project?

Tags: copyright, gaming, assets

I am trying to make my small open-source web project for training purpose and put it on GitHub.

I wanted to use frame from the existing game, but I don't know if I will have any issues from it.

Here is the screenshot from the game (*Icewind Dale 2*) and below the frame I would like to use in my home-made project, just to wrap the text in the box.

I know that many fan Websites are using graphic from games, my Project is used only for learning purposes but i want to store it on github.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Open Source Stack Exchange. What is the license of Icewind Dale 2? Knowing the license of the game is required in order to answer your question.

Comment: How can I check it? I mean, many fan webpages are using graphics from the games (Guild sites, home made wikis and so on)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a pure law question and should be asked at [law.se].

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can find the license for this program, you must assume the copyright holder(s), which is likely the company or developers of the game, have not granted you permission to use the graphic outside of the game. Hence, you would not be allowed to use the graphic in your GitHub repository.

Microsoft explicitly allows you to post in-game footage of their games via a license agreement: https://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/rules.

There are likely a similar set of rules for this game. However, I would be cautious and do not assume this to be true without any evidence.